# React navigation 5 - Move drawer item icon from left to right

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I want to show label on left and drawerIcon on right but unable figure out how.
Here is code

```
<Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContentOptions={{
        contentContainerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
          height: "100%"
        },
        labelStyle: { color: "white" }
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={Home}
        options={{ drawerLabel: "Home" }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Channels"
        component={Channels}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <AntDesign
              name="pluscircle"
              size={20}
              color="white"
            />
          )
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

I would like to show "Channels" on left side and plus icon on right side

Answer (score 4):

on your icon, style it with

```
style={{
  alignSelf: "center",
  position: "absolute",
  right: 5,
}}
```

so your AntDesign will be like this

```
<AntDesign
  style={{
    alignSelf: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    right: 5,
  }}
  name="pluscircle"
  size={20}
  color="white"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `headerLeft` and `headerRight`

```
 headerLeft: () => (
      <Icon
        style={{padding: 10}}
        onPress={() => {
            consol.log("on press}}
        color={'white'}
        name="menu"
        size={30}
      />
```

Comment: In V4x we use `static` in any component to do any option like `headerShown:false` Now in V5 How can i use it?

Comment: @yoel headerLeft? I guess this is only stack navigator's property

Comment: @OliverD within component receive props and then use props.navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: false })

Answer (score -1):

```
  <Drawer.Navigator
  drawerPosition="right"
  drawerType="slide"
  initialRouteName="Home"
  drawerContent={() => <SideBar />}>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="NewIndex" component={NewIndex} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -2):

me am hit this ROCK and stuck under it for hours and kept looking for answers in the whole universe and NOTHING. you know what I mean ...

this dude - Devanada - had a solution, but this one was NOT good for use too

style={{
alignSelf: "center",
position: "absolute",
right: 5,
}}

my solution was simple and more practical

JUST ADD A ...View... then punch an absolute Pos to its face

like this |||||

```
<View
 style={{
 width: 30,
 height: 30,
 position: "absolute",
 right: 8,
 }}
 >
 <Icon
 name={focused ? "user-circle-o" : "user-circle"}
 size={30}
 type="font-awesome"
 color={focused ? "#001FD6" : "black"}
 />
 </View>
```

HAPPY CODING GUYZ